# How to have save a score in Spritekit and Swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

I've looked all over the internet to figure out how to save scores with NSUserDefaults. All of them don't end up working. It may be that they're all from Swift 3. I hope to figure out how to do this in Swift 5 and Spritekit. I am making a game like Flappy Bird called Plane Dash and I would like to save scores and eventually add a high score function.

I have tried this so far: 
[The code I have tried so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9VFm.png)

Answer (score 2):

you can use UserDefualts. for example

```
    var score = 0
    //SET
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "score")
    //RETRIVE
    score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "score")
```

EDIT:

```
var currentScore = 100 //change that to the players current score.
let highScore  = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highScore") //Get the users high score from last time.

if(currentScore > highScore){// check and see if currentScore is greater than highScore.

    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentScore, forKey: "highScore")//if currentScore is greater than highScore, set it in UserDefualts.

}
```

EDIT Pt.2

```
labelName.text! = "\(highScore)"
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to do a high score function with this.

Comment: Thank You a lot! I have tried doing a high score label but does not work. Should I set a variable to the value in the key?

Comment: what do you mean? are you trying to set a labels value based on the UserDefualts?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do

Comment: so then set the UserDefualts to a var

Comment: i tried but it didn't work:                                                                                                     
var highScore  = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highScore")                                                 this was in the class with other variables

Comment: right, now set the label to that var. however, you will need to cast that as a string since that is an integer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean this is what I did so far: var highScore  = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highScore") {
        didSet {
            highLabel.text! = "Highscore: \(highScore)"
        }
    }

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: also, here is Apples documentation on UserDefualts. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: I looked at your answer, and do I put it in my function with the other high score stuff?

Comment: Or in my label function for the high score

Comment: if i put it in my label function it says there is a fatal error

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: make it an optional then, take out the ! in the label

Comment: dude common he shouldn't be doing all of this for you.